# Equivalent EKCalendarChooser in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, calendar, android-calendar

I am trying to implement the clone of EKCalendar in Android but I'm struck in displaying the list of holidays & birthdays. Adding to that, I need to display on the users choice which email does he want to show.

So far the code goes as,

```
private fun loadCalendarEvents(emailString: String) {
    val projectionArray =
        arrayOf(
            CalendarContract.Calendars._ID,
            CalendarContract.Events.TITLE,
            CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION,
            CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART,
            CalendarContract.Events.DTEND,
            CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY,
            CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION,
            CalendarContract.Attendees.ORGANIZER,
            CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_TIME_ZONE,
            CalendarContract.Events.ACCOUNT_TYPE
        )

    val startTime = Calendar.getInstance()

    startTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
    startTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
    startTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)

    var fromTime = registrationPreferences.getFromTime()
    var toTime = registrationPreferences.getToTime()

    when {
        fromTime.equals("6 Months", true) -> {
            startTime.add(Calendar.MONTH, -6)
            startTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
        }
        fromTime.equals("1 Year", true) -> {
            startTime.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1)
        }
        fromTime.equals("2 Years", true) -> {
            startTime.add(Calendar.YEAR, -2)
        }
        fromTime.equals("3 Years", true) -> {
            startTime.add(Calendar.YEAR, -3)
        }
    }

    val endTime = Calendar.getInstance()
    when {
        toTime.equals("6 Months", true) -> {
            endTime.add(Calendar.MONTH, 6)
        }
        toTime.equals("1 Year", true) -> {
            endTime.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1)
        }
        toTime.equals("2 Years", true) -> {
            endTime.add(Calendar.YEAR, 2)
        }
        toTime.equals("3 Years", true) -> {
            endTime.add(Calendar.YEAR, 3)
        }
    }


    val selection =
        "(( " + CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART + " >= " + startTime.timeInMillis + " ) AND ( " + CalendarContract.Events.DTEND + " <= " + endTime.timeInMillis + " ) AND ( deleted != 1 ) " + " AND (${CalendarContract.Calendars.OWNER_ACCOUNT} = ?)" + " AND (${CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_TYPE} = ?))"


    val cursor = contentResolver.query(
        CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI,
        projectionArray,
        selection,
        null,
        null
    )
    if (cursor != null && cursor.count > 0 && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            // Need to fetch the events.
        } while (cursor.moveToNext())
    }
}
```

Help would be really appreciated.